# Promotion, add condition Postal Code range

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

Is there a module to add a range of postal code among the conditions of a promotion? and not individual values like now?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 allows this out of the box. Click on the è in your screenshot and it should give you a dropdown of options including "greater than" and "less than" and using these you can create a range.

[image: Magento 1 shipping postcode conditions]